# Keep model value updated as it changes?

Tags: angularjs

In a AngularApp, how do i keep the value of, lets say, and input field, updated, as the model changes?

For instance, take the following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.myvalue" />
```

Controller

```
vm.myvalue = "10";    
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
   vm.myvalue = map.getZoom();
   console.log(map.getZoom());
});
```

On load, the input field has 10 as the value. But when i change, in this example, the zoom level on the map, it does not get updated. But the events is being fired, as i can see the correct value in the console?

Comment: what is this `ctrl.myvalue` ?is it a controller varialble or scope variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to the fact that vm.myvalue is not being digested in the watch-digest cycle, as you are triggering value change asynchronously.

Check if this works.,

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
   $scope.$apply(function(){
       vm.myvalue = map.getZoom();
   });
   console.log(map.getZoom());
   });
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

to do the two way data binding in angularjs, the myvalue variable must be a scope variable , so your code should be like this :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myvalue" />



$scope.myvalue = "10";    
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
   $scope.myvalue = map.getZoom();
   console.log(map.getZoom());
});
```